# Case in Query Update

Tags: sql

I have this Query,

```
request.query('update empleados_lineas 
  set Sucursal=(select codigo from sucursal where DESCRIPCION = @sucursal), 
      Usuario=@operador, 
      Plan_linea = (select ID_planes from planes where descripcion = @plan), 
      NUMERO = (select Numero from transportistas where Razonsocial = @Rsocial), 
     cta_cont = (select id from Cuentas where Cta_contable = @CtaContable), 
     updatefecha = @date, 
     updateusuario=@usuario 
  where Nro_linea=@Linea'
```

Im trying to add a CASE sentence in **cta_cont**

```
cta_cont =(
CASE  When @plan='5' Then '600102006' 
When @Rsocial='TRADELOG S.A' then '600104002'Else '590103002'  END 
where Cta_contable = @CtaContable)
```

but i get and error,

Is that posible?

Comment: Looks as if you have a redundant `WHERE ... ` clause, as you have removed the `SELECT` part of your statement.

Comment: `but i get and error,` ← Elaborate on the details of the error like line number, message, exception information if any, etc.

Comment: `request.query()` <- which language are you using?

Comment: I think you don't need the `where` clause anyway. Apparently that column doesn't need a lookup in the other table. Just use the `case` expression alone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out the column name in the `CASE STATEMENT`, which should be specified by the `<AS column_name>`  at the end of the Case clause. So its confusing the `where` with the column_name.

The general format of the Case statement is as follows:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END as col_name
```

In your specific case see if this works:

```
cta_cont =(
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @plan='5' THEN '600102006'
         WHEN @Rsocial='TRADELOG S.A' THEN '600104002'
         ELSE '590103002' END AS ID
FROM Cuentas
WHERE Cta_contable = @CtaContable)
```

As others have stated the `where` clause may or may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is unnecessary. Just use the expression.

```
cta_cont =
    case when @plan = '5' then '600102006' 
         when @Rsocial = 'TRADELOG S.A' then '600104002'
         else '590103002'
    end,
```